# How to use firstobs in the infile?

Tags: sas

I have been using `firstobs` in the `set`

```
data test ; 
set test (firstobs=5) ; 
run ;
```

Recently I saw a code

```
data test ;
infile 'C:xxx' firstobs=5 ;
input xxx ; 
run ;
```

I tried running it but it did not work . Is it possible to use `firstobs` in the `infile`

Comment: try using just `obs = `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use firstobs like that.

From the [documentation for infile](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm):

```
infile file-specification firstobs=50 obs=100;
```

would read observations 50 through 100.